# Using kartik SideNav widget in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I am using kartik SideNav widget in my project. I want the menu active and open when I click on it but it not works.Actually I dont know about $item and $type variables that how to use in the sidenav. thanx in advance for solving it.

my code is below.

```
$type = SideNav::TYPE_PRIMARY; 
$item = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;

echo SideNav::widget([
'type' => $type,
'encodeLabels' => false,

'items' => [

    ['label' => 'Home', 'icon' => 'home', 'url' => Url::to(['/site/index']), 'active' => ($item == 'index')],

    ['label' => '<span class="pull-right badge">2</span> Products', 'icon' => 'book', 'items' => [
        ['label' => '<span class="pull-right badge"></span> Products', 'url' => Url::to(['/products']), 'active' => ($item == 'http://localhost/test_project_yii2/backend/web/products')],
        ['label' => '<span class="pull-right badge"></span> Add Product', 'url' => Url::to(['/products/create']), 'active' => ($item == '/products/create')],
    ]],

],
```

]);

Answer (score 0):

`$item` is id of your action, like `actionCreate` will output here `create`.

Add here:

```
$controllerId = Yii::$app->controller->id;
```

Which will output `products` for `ProductsController`.

In option `active` use:

```
'active' => $controller == 'products' && $item == 'create'
```

And you should rename `$item` to `$actionId` or something similiar.